# Runging own Telgram bot based on PTB 13x and local Telegram bot API behind nginx

Tags: nginx, python, docker-compose

Try to use local Telegram bot API to take benefits of larger files for my bot serving and helping users in supergroup with files [as described here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server)
Build stack with Telegram Bot API, nginx as reverse proxy and my bot works ok, based on [docker-compose template](https://github.com/aiogram/telegram-bot-api/tree/master/example):

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  int:
    name: internal
    driver: bridge

services:
  api:
    hostname: local-api
    image: aiogram/telegram-bot-api:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - int
    environment:
      TELEGRAM_API_ID: BOT_ID
      TELEGRAM_API_HASH: BOT_HASH
      TELEGRAM_LOCAL: "true"
      TELEGRAM_HTTP_IP_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0
      TELEGRAM_HTTP_PORT: 8081
      TELEGRAM_MAX_FILESIZE: 1000000000 # задава максимален размер на файла на 1GB
    volumes:
      - telegram-bot-api-data:/var/lib/telegram-bot-api

  nginx:
    hostname: nginx
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - telegram-bot-api-data:/var/lib/telegram-bot-api
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - "88:88"
    networks:
      - int

  telegram-bot:
    depends_on:
     - api
     - nginx
    hostname : telegram-bot
    networks:
      - int
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: /root/docker/telegram-bot
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: telegram-bot/latest
    environment:
      LOCAL_API_URL: http://nginx:88/bot
      LOCAL_API_FILES: http://nginx:88/file/bot
    labels:
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=false"
    volumes:
      - /root/docker/telegram-bot/:/app/

volumes:
  telegram-bot-api-data:
```

And accoring nginx config with redirects:

```
# use $sanitized_request instead of $request to hide Telegram token
log_format token_filter '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                        '"$sanitized_request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

upstream telegram-bot-api {
    server local-api:8081;
}

server {
    listen 88;

    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    client_body_buffer_size 30M;
    keepalive_timeout 0;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    rewrite_log on;

    set $sanitized_request $request;
    if ( $sanitized_request ~ (\w+)\s(\/bot\d+):[-\w]+\/(\S+)\s(.*) ) {
        set $sanitized_request "$1 $2:<hidden-token>/$3 $4";
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log token_filter;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

    location ~* \/file\/bot\d+:(.*) {
        rewrite ^/file\/bot(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        try_files $uri @files;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @api;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
    }

    location @files {
        root /var/lib/telegram-bot-api;
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 64 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
    }

    location @api {
        proxy_pass  http://telegram-bot-api;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

At last Telegram bot is setup to work with local Telegram Bot API:

```
.env
LOCAL_API=True
LOCAL_API_URL=http://nginx:88/bot
LOCAL_API_FILES=http://nginx:88/file/bot
```

PTB telegram bot setup

```
updater = Updater(config["BOT_TOKEN"], use_context = True, base_url = config["LOCAL_API_URL"], base_file_url = config["LOCAL_API_FILES"], arbitrary_callback_data = True)
```

Things works fine but file redirect wont work as expect - the limit is still on and can't get local link for received from bot file

> 2023/04/04 11:15:52 [error] 30#30: *15 open()
> "/var/lib/telegram-bot-api/TOKEN_ID:TOKEN_HASH/var/lib/telegram-bot-api/TOKEN_ID:TOKEN_HASH/documents/file_16.apk"
> failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.4, server: _,
> request: "GET
> /file/botTOKEN_ID%3ATOKEN_HASH//var/lib/telegram-bot-api/TOKEN_ID%3ATOKEN_HASH/documents/file_16.apk
> HTTP/1.1", host: "nginx:81"
> 172.19.0.4 - - [04/Apr/2023:11:15:52 +0000] "GET /file/botTOKEN_ID%3ATOKEN_HASH//var/lib/telegram-bot-api/TOKEN_ID%3ATOKEN_HASH/documents/file_16.apk
> HTTP/1.1" 404 154 "-" "Python Telegram Bot
> (https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)"

There is "dublicate path" in logs
**/var/lib/telegram-bot-api/TOKEN_ID:TOKEN_HASH/var/lib/telegram-bot-api/TOKEN_ID:TOKEN_HASH/documents/file_16.apk**

But despite of that curl request works as expected

```
curl -i http://nginx:81/file/botTOKEN_ID:TOKEN_HASH/documents/file_16.apk
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.19.10 Date: Tue, 04 Apr 2023 14:31:01
> GMT Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length: 10066456
> Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Apr 2023 06:26:47 GMT Connection: close ETag:
> "642bc327-999a18" Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to
> tell Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider
> "--output Warning: " to save to a file.

Can't realize from where become error, bot itslef request to local API or nginx redirects ?
Rewriting bot at PTB 20.x is not an option do not have enough time for probono project.
Any ideas are welcome!